# EventMachine is terrifyingly slow

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

Is there any reason that in my application, the `send_data` method lags terribly? My telnet (many other clients tested with same result) window wait 1-2 seconds before displying the data sent.

The following application has no lag:

```
require 'eventmachine'

class AreaServer < EventMachine::Connection
  attr_accessor :options, :status

  def receive_data(data)
    send_data("I got: #{data}\r\n")
  end
end

EM.run do
  EM.start_server '192.168.0.199', 4000, AreaServer do |conn|
    conn.options = {:my => 'options'}
    conn.status = :OK
  end
end
```

so I suspect it's not a networking problem.

Comment: No idea. I've pasted your code to console (replaced '192...' with '127.0.0.1' and port with 8001) and it echoes immediately via telnet.

Comment: @philpirozhkov: Yeah, that piece of code works perfectly fine. I was talking about another project (way too long to post) which lags pretty badly (it's not the code in that that's lagging, my log shows that the data is send 1-2 seconds before it has been recieved). I just wanted to know if there were something I was doing wrong with send_data that was causing the lag.

Comment: Post your lagging code and we will try to figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the output stream kept open after writing, so I tried to find a solution to close this stream.

If you write `close_connection_after_writing` to `receive_data`, the stream will be closed after write. I guess you should turn off the keep_alive option.

```
class AreaServer < EventMachine::Connection
  attr_accessor :options, :status

  def receive_data(data)
    send_data("I got: #{data}\n")
    close_connection_after_writing
  end
end
```

Comment: So after sending data close the connection? I don't think that will work because I'm writing a MUD server :\

Comment: First I just wanted to find the reason of lagging, now I see some frameworks for more details.

Comment: Now I tried it again with telnet, but it's not lagging for me... Maybe a network problem?

Comment: My (larger) application lags, but the example one I included doesn't. That was the main reason I suspected that it was not a network error. But, I'll make sure that it is not the case by running this on a different machine. Thanks :)